# If I have Pthread code on Linux, is there an advantage to implementing the same code in std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads, stdthread

I'm doing a little university project where I apply different multi-threading approaches to pattern matching algorithms (pthread, omp) and compare them against their respective sequential implementations.

At the moment it works well, and depending on the algorithm and gcc optimizations, I get shorter run times by a factor of about 2 - 3.

Now, I'd like to do it using std::thread as well, however, from what I've managed to gather, they're implemented using Pthreads on Linux, so I was wondering whether there was any point to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::thread` is a feature provided by the ISO C++ standard language, so it will be available on platforms and implementations which are compliant to C++11, `pthread`s on the other hand adheres to IEEE standard and so not a part of the C++ standard.

So if your application or multithreaded code needs to run on various platforms then it would make sense to use `std::thread` so that it just works as it is on all platforms without any modification at all. if you are not worried of cross platform compatibility then you are just fine with `pthread`s.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. You can do the same with both APIs, but:

- pthreads are a part of POSIX, and as such, are available on pretty much any *nix OS, but not (natively) on Windows.
- pthreads is a C API: you can easily call it from C code, but it does not take advantage of C++ features to make the API nicer/safer to use
- `std::thread` is a standard C++ API. It isn't part of a separate specification outside the language (like pthreads is part of POSIX, rather than C or C++). As such, is is available on any platform which has a modern C++ compiler (including both *nix and Windows)
- `std::thread` is a C++ API, so you can't call it from C --- but on the other hand, it is easier and safer to use. It utilizes RAII heavily to ensure that resources get cleaned up when they go out of scope, and it allows you to create a thread from a function object, with all the flexibility that gives you, rather than being constrained to a C-style free function.

So it depends. If you want your code to be used from C as well as C++, you might want to stick with pthreads. On the other hand, if it is C++ only, and you want it to work regardless of OS, then `std::thread` is preferable. And if you just want to write *nice* C++ code, `std::thread` is the way to go too.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Alok Save's answer concerning portability (which is a big advantage in itself)...

`pthreads` is a C API, as such it doesn't provide any RAII wrapper which makes it harder to use and more error-prone, especially as far as exception safety is concerned (unless you wrote your own wrappers, which you now have to debug and maintain).

`std::thread` et al provide well tested, exception-safe, modern C++ wrappers as well as a number of conveniences (eg. support for lambdas, `std::function`, `std::bind`, ...) that make it much easier and safer to use. For example, this code would be much more painful to write and debug with `pthreads`:

```
std::mutex m;

struct ThreadClass {
    ThreadClass(int p1, int p2, int p3)
        : t(std::bind(&ThreadClass::run, this, p1, p2, p3))
    // notice how I'm binding to a member function, not a static one
    // additionally I'm also binding additional parameters, which
    // avoids using member variables
    {}
    void run(int p1, int p2, int p3) {
        {
            auto l = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(m);
            // do something while locked
            // the lock will be automatically released when you
            // exit the scope, no matter how (including return and throw)
        }
        // continue unlocked
    }
    std::thread t;
}

void fireAndForget(int param) {
    std::thread t([=]() {
            // do something with param (captured by the lambda)
        });
    t.detach();
}
```